# How to implement "like" in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run a simple query making a restriction of like % in [BigQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery), but LIKE is not in their syntax, so how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the REGEXP_MATCH function (see the query reference [page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference)):
REGEXP_MATCH('str', 'reg_exp')

Instead of using the % syntax used by LIKE, you should use regular expressions (detailed syntax definition [here](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax))

Answer (score 14):

LIKE is officially supported in BigQuery Standard SQL -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#comparison_operators

And I think it also works in Legacy SQL!

Comment: Seems that the LIKE operator is limited in its Google Cloud implementation. I haven't been able to use character list feature (using brackets) for example. The official documentation only indicates the possible use of % and _, which makes it limited to fewer use cases than RegEx.

Answer (score 7):

REGEXP_MATCH returns true if str matches the regular expression. For string matching without regular expressions, use CONTAINS instead of REGEXP_MATCH.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#stringfunctions

Answer (score 1):

REGEXP_MATCH is great if you know how to use it, but for those who aren't sure there won't be any commonly used special characters such as '.','$' or '?' in the lookup string, you can use `LEFT('str', numeric_expr)` or `RIGHT('str', numeric_expr)`.
ie if you had a list of names and wanted to return all those that are LIKE 'sa%'
you'd use:

`select name from list where LEFT(name,2)='sa';` (with 2 being the length of 'sa')

Additionally, if you wanted to say where one column's values are LIKE another's, you could swap out the 2 for `LENGTH(column_with_lookup_strings)` and `='sa'` for `=column_with_lookup_strings`, leaving it looking something like this:

`select name from list where LEFT(name,LENGTH(column_with_lookup_strings))= column_with_lookup_strings;`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Answer (score 0):

Like works in BigQuery with a small change, just change the datatype on the left to string and then run it.

For example:
If you wish to apply like on a column bus_dt and its defined as date (or anything) in table then change it to string like below.

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE STRING(bus_dt) LIKE '%2023%';